# Seg fault while parsing a line into ***char

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, char, segmentation-fault

My code is supposed to parse an array of chars into ***char, so that it splits it first by '|' char and then by whitespaces, newline characters etc into words. Sample i/o:

```
I = ls -l | sort | unique
```

O =

```
  *cmds[1] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
  *cmds[2] = {"sort", NULL};
  *cmds[3] = {"unique", NULL};
```

above are pointers to char arrays, so split by words and then below is ***char with pointers to above pointers

```
  char **cmds[] = {1, 2, 3, NULL};
```

Now, I don't see my mistake (probably because I am not so skilled in C), but program gives segfault the second I call parse(..) function from inside parsePipe(). Can anyone please help?

```
void parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
        while (*line != '\0') {     
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
            *line++ = '\0'; 
        *argv++ = line;     
        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n'){
            line++;
        }
    }
    *argv = '\0';  
}

void parsePipe(char *line, char ***cmds)
{
    char *cmd = strtok(line, "|");
    int word_counter = 0;

    while (cmd != NULL) 
    {
       printf("Printing word -> %s\n", cmd);
       word_counter++; 
       parse(cmd, *cmds++);

       cmd = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }

    printf("This string contains %d words separated with |\n",word_counter);
}


void  main(void)
{
    char  line[1024];          
    char  **cmds[64]; 
    while (1) {    
        printf("lsh -> ");   
        gets(line);     
        printf("\n");
        parsePipe(line, cmds);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this? `char *1[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};` You can't name a variable starting with a number.

Comment: This isn't code, it's a sample i/o to show how it should look like..

Comment: `argv` by convention is `char**`. Do not call a chair a table.

Comment: Does your program print any output? Try flushing buffers right before you think it crashes and see what it prints.

Comment: Well it prints the word with printf in parsePipes and then goes into segfault, when I put printf at the beginning of parse() it didn't print.

Comment: How are commenters supposed to distinguish between code with accidental errors and code with deliberate errors?

Comment: Reformatted a bit, changed the variable name aswell

Comment: Still does not make sense really, as incomplete and not in sync with source.

Answer (score 1):

[too long for a comment]

This line

```
*argv++ = line; /* with char ** argv */
```

refers to invalid memory, as the code does `*argv[n]` (with char `**argv[64]`) which refers nothing.

The namings you use do not make live easier.

Try the following naming:

```
void parse(char *line, char **cmd)
{
    while (*line != '\0') {     
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
            *line++ = '\0'; 
        *cmd++ = line;     
        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n'){
            line++;
        }
    }
    *argv = '\0';  
}

void parsePipe(char *line, char ***cmdline)
{
    char *cmd = strtok(line, "|");
    int word_counter = 0;

    while (cmd != NULL) 
    {
       printf("Printing word -> %s\n", cmd);
       word_counter++; 
       parse(cmd, *cmdline++);

       cmd = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }

    printf("This string contains %d words separated with |\n",word_counter);
}


void  main(void)
{
    char  line[1024];          
    char  **cmdline[64]; 
    while (1) {    
        printf("lsh -> ");   
        gets(line);     
        printf("\n");
        parsePipe(line, cmdline);
    }
}
```

For none of the `cmd`s used memory had been allocated.

So

```
*cmd++ = line;
```

fails, as `cmd` points nowhere, but gets dereferenced and the code tries to write to where it's pointing, which is nowhere, that is invalid memory.

---

Fixing this can be done by passing `char***` to `parse(char *** pcmd)` and counting the tokens found

```
size_t nlines = 0;

...

++nlines.
```

and the doing a

```
*pcmd = realloc(*pcmd, nlines + 1); /* Allocate one more as needed to later find the end of the array. */
(*pcmd)[nlines -1] = line;
(*pcmd)[nlines] = NULL; /* Initialise the stopper, marking the end of the array. */
```

for each token found.

Obviously you need to call it like this:

```
 parse(cmd, cmdline++);
```

To have all this work the inital array needs to initialised properly (as you should have done anyway):

```
char  **cmdline[64] = {0};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just one more thing - you use realloc, shouldn't we first malloc the variable? If so, then with what, nlines = 0?

Comment: @user3885166: Doing `void * p = NULL; p = realloc(p, 42);` is the same as `void * p = malloc(1); p = reallc(p, 42);` or even `void * p = realloc(NULL, 42);`

Comment: @user3885166: For `nlines = 0` you can either skip the `realloc` and just assign `NULL` to `*pcmd` or if already initialised to `NULL`  from the beginning simply do nothing. If support by your compiler you can also do `(*pcmd) = realloc(pcmd, 0);` but beware that for this latter case you need to call `free(*pcmd)`. Which would not be necessary if you'd define an empty "*command*" being indicating by `*pcmd = NULL`.

Comment: Unfortunately when I used *pcmd = NULL it gives me segfault again, so that's not quite right. I initialized properly **cmdline[64] = {0}, but as soon as it reached parse() it segfaults again.

Comment: Use a debugger, to trace your code and inspect the values of all relevant variables.

Comment: @user3885166: You did change the code to `parse(char *** pcmd)` and call it like this `parse(cmd, cmdline++);`?

Comment: Yes, parse(char *line, char ***pcmd) and parse(cmd, cmdline++). I am soon out of time so I guess I'll just give up.